# How do sites like Hubspot track inbound links?

Tags: api, seo, screen-scraping

Are all these types of sites just illegally scraping Google or another search engine?
As far as I can tell ther is no 'legal' way to get this data for a commercial site.. The Yahoo! api ( http://developer.yahoo.com/search/siteexplorer/V1/inlinkData.html ) is only for noncommercial use, Yahoo! Boss does not allow automated queries etc.
Any ideas?

Comment: They could just crawl the web... sites like http://www.80legs.com/ make it easier.

Answer (score 4):

For example, if you wanted to find all the links to Google's homepage, search for

```
link:http://www.google.com
```

So if you want to find all the inbound links, you can simply traverse your website's tree, and for each item it finds, build a URL. Then query Google for:

```
link:URL
```

And you'll get a collection of all the links that Google has from other websites into your website.

As for the legality of such harvesting, I'm sure it's not-exactly-legal to make a profit from it, but that's never stopped anyone before, has it?

(So I wouldn't bother wondering whether they did it or not. Just assume they do.)

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what hubspot do, but, if you wanted to find out what sites link to your site, and you don't have the hardware to crawl the web, one thing you can do is monitor the HTTP_REFERER of visitors to your site. This is, for example, how Google Analytics (as far as I know) can tell you where your visitors are arriving from. This is not 100% reliable as not all browsers set it, particularly in "Privacy Mode", but you only need one visitor per link to know that it exists!

This is ofter accomplished by embedding a script into each of your webpages (often in a common header or footer). For example, if you examine the source for the page you are currently reading you will find (right down at the bottom) a script that reports back to Google information about your visit.

Now this won't tell you if there are links out there that no one has ever used to get to your site, but let's face it, they are a lot less interesting than the ones people actually use.

Comment: Exactly right, I think -- looking at Hubspot's sample screenshots, you can see that every single tracked inbound link has had at one visitor from it. To expound, the referrer data can be obtained from logs or via having something embedded in your site.